# Could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database ERROR but still everything works

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-orm

I've created user and userRole tables

user entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "USERNAME",  nullable = false,  unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "ENABLED", nullable = false)
    private boolean enabled = true;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<>();
```

userRole entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_ROLES", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(
        columnNames = { "ROLE", "USERNAME" }))
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_role_id",
            unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer userRoleId;

    @Column(name = "ROLE")
    private String role;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME")
    private User user;
```

When i launch my app i get an Error and this stack trace:

```
ERROR JdbcEnvironmentImpl:420 - Could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "start_with" not found [42122-197]
```

But i don't have any 'start_with' columns. Before my UserRole entity was without userRoleId column and everything worked fine but then i added it to do 'role' column not unique and then this happened. But still everything works fine, i just disturbed by this error, what can be the couse of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest checking your Hibernate dialect.

I had a similar error because of a `start_value` column that Hibernate was looking for in sequences of my PostgresQL database. This field name is a default value in Hibernate's `SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl` class which has many subclasses, each depending on your precise database server and its version. Hibernate loads the right class according to the dialect you specify.

In my case, I was using the `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect` dialect, a (deprecated) class meant to be used with a PostgesQL 8.2 version. I switched to `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect` since my database was hosted on a PostgresQL 9 server. And the issue was gone.

Comment: I'm using org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect.

Comment: Indeed, you have only one possible dialect for Hsql database.
I was wrong in any case : I thought my error had disappeared but it was still there. The real cause of my issue is this bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13291

Comment: After almost a year i googled the same question and found my question here. Red it again and i understood that this man was right. I was using wrong dialect all this time.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, can you please tell me even with this error, why application works, and there is no issue

Comment: probably because try catch hidden inside dialect. It can't find column but ignores this error and goes on.